# How to get grand total of columns in mongodb aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using mongodb aggregate to show reports. my query is below :

```
db.campaigns_report.aggregate([
   { '$match' : { } },
   { '$group' : {
      '_id': '$campaignId', 
      'campaignName' : { '$first': '$campaignName' },
      'impressions' : { '$sum': '$impressions' }
   }
  },
  { '$project' : {'campaignName': '$campaignName', 'impressions': '$impressions'} },
  { '$facet'    : {
    'metadata': [ { '$count': "total"} ],
    'data': [ { '$skip': 0 },{ '$limit': 10 } ]
  } 
 }
]);
```

In the above query I want total sum of impressions in `$facet` along with total document count. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get total sum of impressions along with total document count you need to run [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#group-by-null) specifying `null` as grouping `_id` and use [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/index.html) operator twice:

```
db.campaigns_report.aggregate([
    { '$match' : { } },
    { '$group' : {
        '_id': '$campaignId', 
        'campaignName' : { '$first': '$campaignName' },
        'impressions' : { '$sum': '$impressions' }
    }
    },
    { '$project' : {'campaignName': '$campaignName', 'impressions': '$impressions'} },
    { '$facet'    : {
        'metadata': [ { '$group': { _id: null, total: { $sum: 1 }, totalImpressions: { $sum: '$impressions' } } } ],
        'data': [ { '$skip': 0 },{ '$limit': 10 } ]
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NHbiwTr-B6S)